# Fetch data from a Python dictionary dynamically?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I fetch data from a dictionary in a predefined order.

For example in the dictionary below, how can I fetch join1 values first and then join2 and so on if there are more dynamically so that I can iterate through the whole dictionary and fetch values one by one without hard coding anything?

```
jDict = dict(join1 = dict(jtable='ABC', alias='REF', joinSelColumns=['A'],
                             joinCond=['B', 'C', 'D'],
                             joinGroupClause=['B', 'C', 'D'],
                             joinOrderClause=[('B', 'DESC'), ('C'), ('D')]),
                join2 = dict(jtable='XYZ', alias = 'NET', joinSelColumns=['S'],
                             joinCond=['T'],
                             joinGroupClause=['M', 'N'],
                             joinOrderClause=[('M', 'DESC'), ('N')]))
```

Comment: Not possible. But possible with [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: If your keys are all called `join[n]` and you want to iterate over them in order, why not just use a list? Using a dictionary has literally no advantage in that case.

Comment: Look at collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the keys:

```
for sortedkey in sorted(jDict):
    # first join1, then join2
```

Otherwise, dictionaries have no set order.

You could use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead though; it  maintains items in insertion order; if `join1` is inserted before `join2` then it'll also be listed first when iterating over the dictionary.

If all you have are otherwise equal items, only differing in order (so *just* `join1`, `join2`, etc.) you may as well just use a list instead. Even if you had different types of items, you could also *group* those items by type; `jDict['joins'] = [join1, join2, etc.]`.